# background location iOS 8

Tags: background, ios8, location, updates, locationmanager

Hello Devs: I am working on an app where I would like to fetch users location in background and send push notifications to him as soon as the user arrives at that particular location. Here is what I have done so far with my locatioManager in my app delegate

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

I have set up my info.plist to always request location. I also get the message that my app will be using location in the background when I install the app on my device. However when I close the app and arrive at the specific location I don't get any push notifications or alerts until I launch the app. I turned on Background mode --> location updates under capabilities section and then everything works absolutely fine. I receive notification seamlessly without launching the app. This is all good but when I close the app I see a blue bar on my status bar saying that my app is tracking the location in background. How do I hide that blue bar on the top? I am pretty sure this is going to scare away my users and they will remove my app instantly. To make long story short how do I accomplish this? I know this question has been asked and answered several times in past but all those answers are 2-3 years old and don't seem to work with new iOS 8. I need to get the user location in background in order for my app to work or else its useless. I will really appreciate any help or suggestions to this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called (background) Geofencing. Your app doesn't need to calculate it by itself since CoreLocation already offers this feature.

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17174344/598812) from [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662605/daniel).

The Geofencing feature will wake up your app when the users gets into the target zone, and will not display the blue bar.